# problem exporting an Animate video

Tags: export, animation

Here's my code:

```
movie = Animate[
  Plot[x + a, {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], {a, 1, 5}, 
  AnimationDirection -> Forward, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
  AnimationRunning -> False]
Export["movie.avi", movie]
```

In the video in the Mathematica window, the sweep of the parameter 'a' goes from 1 to 5, and there's a single sweep. However, in the exported video, it appears a double sweep: from 1 to 5 and then is reversed, from 5 to 1. How to avoid this?? How to obtain a video with the exact animation shown in the Mathematica window??

Thank you!!! :-)

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this is unexpected. I was able to reproduce the problem in MMA 10.1 on Win7-64bit. This looks like a bug within `Export` to me, which I think you should report to WRI.

In the meantime, you can generate the frames yourself, then use `ListAnimate` to generate a movie for export with the same format (controls, panes) that you would get from `Animate`:

```
frames = Table[
               Plot[x + a, {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {0, 7}], 
               {a, 1, 5, 0.1}
           ];
movielist = ListAnimate[frames, AnimationDirection -> Forward, AnimationRepetitions -> 1];
Export["movielist.avi", movielist]
```

Comment: Thank you MarcoB for your answer... Finally I did it like you suggested, and I saw in the forums that this is the best solution when exporting videos!

Comment: @cricricombowino If you think that my answer above is an acceptable solution to your problem, would you consider formally accepting it by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it?